# tab-delimited file output inconsistent

Tags: python-2.7, delimiter

I am attempting to write elements from a nested list to individual lines in a file, with each element separated by tab characters. Each of the nested lists is of the following form:

```
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```

The final output should be of the form:

```
A    B    C    D
E    F    G    H
.    .    .    .
.    .    .    .
```

However, my output seems to have reproducible inconsistencies such that the output is of the general form:

```
A    B    C    D
E    F    G H
I    J    K L
M    N    O    P
.    .    .    .
.    .    .    .
```

I've inspected the lists before writing and they seem identical in form. The code I'm using to write is:

```
with open("letters.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines('\t'.join(line) + '\n' for line in letter_list)
```

Importantly, if I replace '\t' with, for example, '|', the file is created without such inconsistencies. I know whitespace parsing can become an issue for certain file I/O operations, but I don't know how to troubleshoot it here.

Thanks for the time.

EDIT: Here is some actual input data (in nested-list form) and output:

IN

```
('5', '+', '5752624-5752673', 'alt_region_8161'), ('1', '+', '621461-622139', 'alt_region_67'), ('1', '+', '453907-454063', 'alt_region_60'), ('1', '+', '539611-539815', 'alt_region_61'), ('4', '+', '14610049-14610103', 'alt_region_6893'), ('4', '+', '14610049-14610144', 'alt_region_6895'), ('4', '+', '14610049-14610144', 'alt_region_6897'), ('4', '+', '14610049-14610144', 'alt_region_6896')]
```

OUT

```
4   +   12816011-12816087   alt_region_6808
1   +   21214720-21214747   alt_region_2377
4   +   9489968-9490833 alt_region_7382
1   +   12121545-12126263   alt_region_650
4   +   9489968-9490811 alt_region_7381
4   +   12816011-12816087   alt_region_6807
1   +   2032338-2032740 alt_region_157
5   +   4695084-4695628 alt_region_9316
1   +   22294677-22295134   alt_region_2424
1   +   22294677-22295139   alt_region_2425
1   +   22294677-22295139   alt_region_2426
1   +   22294677-22295139   alt_region_2427
1   +   22294677-22295134   alt_region_2422
1   +   22294677-22295134   alt_region_2423
1   +   22294384-22295198   alt_region_2428
1   +   22294384-22295198   alt_region_2429
5   +   20845105-20845211   alt_region_9784
5   +   20845105-20845206   alt_region_9783
3   +   2651447-2651889 alt_region_5562
```

EDIT: Thanks to everyone who commented. Sorry if the question was poorly phrased. I appreciate the help in clarifying the issue (or, apparently, non-issue).

Comment: Did you copy your output here, or did you retype it?

Comment: How long are the elements? If `G` for example is actually 5 characters long that would explain some of the problems.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr the elements are more variable than my example; here is an actual example: 5 + 16665283-16667171 alt_region_9644

Comment: @senshin I just retyped it. I have now noticed that copy/pasting produces unexpected results. Is there a way to ensure uniform formatting?

Comment: Can you give us some actual input to test our selves to help resolve your problem, or should we keep playing 20 questions?

Comment: @glarue Spacing is not necessarily preserved in comments. You must edit your output into your post and use code formatting to guarantee that spacing is preserved. Also, as Lego Stormtroopr said, it would help if you gave us some actual input to work with.

Comment: @glarue In any case, if your fields are of varying length (e.g. in one row, the field is less than a tab long, and in another row, the field is more than a tab long), then of course they won't necessarily align.  Tabs aren't magical visual-spacing-alignment devices.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I'm sorry, I'm not trying to be obtuse it's just that the input data is a bit unwieldy.

Comment: @senshin I understand that given varying element lengths, all of the columns will not line up in every row in the output file. However, what I'm getting is some columns where the elements seem to be separated by spaces, rather than tabs. If it's simply that they're being displayed incorrectly it's all good, but what struck me was the fact that it was not consistent across the output.

Comment: @glarue I've updated my answer with information on how to achieve visually pleasing output. This may not be useful if you have to have a tab-delimited file, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some text editors, tabs are displayed like that. The contents of the file are correct, it's just a matter of how the file is displayed on screen. It happens with tabs but not with `|` which is why you don't see it happening when you use `|`.

Comment: Thanks; looks like this is probably it. Frustrating to the uninformed.

Answer (score 3):

There are no spaces (`' '`)in your output, only tabs (`'\t'`).

```
>>> print(repr('1   +   21214720-21214747   alt_region_2377'))
'1\t+\t21214720-21214747\talt_region_2377'
  ^^ ^^                 ^^
```

Tabs are *not* equivalent to a fixed number of spaces (in most editors). Rather, they move the character following the tab to the next available multiple of `x` characters from the left margin, where `x` varies - `x` is most commonly 8, though it is 4 here on SO.

```
>>> for i in range(7):
    print('x'*i+'\tx')


    x
x   x
xx  x
xxx x
xxxx    x
xxxxx   x
xxxxxx  x
```

---

If you want your output to *appear* aligned to the naked eye, you should use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> for line in data:
    print('{:4} {:4} {:20} {:20}'.format(*line))


5    +    5752624-5752673      alt_region_8161     
1    +    621461-622139        alt_region_67       
1    +    453907-454063        alt_region_60       
1    +    539611-539815        alt_region_61       
4    +    14610049-14610103    alt_region_6893     
4    +    14610049-14610144    alt_region_6895     
4    +    14610049-14610144    alt_region_6897     
4    +    14610049-14610144    alt_region_6896
```

Note, however, that this will not necessarily be readable by code that expects a tab-separated value file.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum. While true that in my case all I care about is correct algorithm parsing, this is a good tip with general applicability.